# Как настроить определение языка сайта?

Tags: php

Я нашла вот такой код. Но не понимаю, как реализовать для моего варианта. У меня статический сайт, в котором 4 файла для разных языков. Когда я прописала `echo $sites[$lang];` мне показывает `/index-fr.php` , то есть отрабатывает все верно, но не работает перенаправление. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
    <?php
// Создаем массив с адресами для каждого языкового кода

$sites = array(

"it" => "/index-it.php",

"en" => "/",

"de" => "/index-de.php",

"fr" => "/index-fr.php",

);

// получаем язык

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); // вырезаем первые две буквы

// проверяем язык



// перенаправление на субдомен

header('Location: /index-'.$sites[$lang].'.php');

echo $sites[$lang];
?>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вопрос не понятен

Comment: @mepihindeveloper не работают перенаправления (

Comment: А что происходит вместо перенаправлений?

Comment: @andreymal Просто загружается главная страница

Comment: а как вы меняете заголовок запроса, чтобы проверить данный код?

Comment: @teran Я ничего не меняла и не дописывала. А нужно? Я слаба в php

Comment: А у вас меняется `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`? Просто если нет, то по умолчанию, судя по коду, вы всегда будете на языке `en`, что сделает редирект на текущей странице. Чтобы проверить работу надо попробовать руками или через форму какую-то изменить язык. В таком случае, Вам надо работать не через `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`, а какую-то переменную. Для автоматизированного решения Ваш код подходит

Comment: Поправила вопрос

Comment: Ну вам точно надо использовать не так `header('Location: /index-'.$sites[$lang].'.php');`, а так: `header("Location: {$sites[$lang]}");` А у вас случаем `.htaccess` не настроен на постоянный редирект в index.php?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper файла  .htaccess нет вообще

Comment: А можете куда-то скинуть свой проект полностью, чтобы проверить у себя?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper https://yadi.sk/d/K_E4pCV9tWB33Q

Comment: @АннаМатвеева я проверил ваш код и он работает. Вы можете убедиться, если перед `header` напишете `$lang = 'de';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что касаемо вашего случая:
У вас index и '.php' в функции перенаправления лишние, да и «слэш» перед «index» не нужен. Массив у вас возвращает полностью ссылку, а вы еще и сами написали «index-» и «.php» и у вас получилось что то типа «index-index-de.php.php».

Попробуйте так (в этом случае массив вообще не нужен):

`header('Location: index-' . $lang . 'php');`

А если хотите с массивом, то так (@mepihindeveloper этот способ в комментарии вам уже предложил):

`header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]);`

Но так же у вас нет никакой проверки на случай, если у пользователя будет язык, которого в вашем списке нет. Нужно сделать проверку и в случае, если языка пользователя у вас нет, автоматически давать ему, например, `en`.
Можно сделать так:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);//Берем первые буквы языка браузера пользователя.

$acceptLang = ['ru', 'de', 'en'];//Ваши языки.

$lang = in_array($lang, $acceptLang) ? $lang : 'en';//Сравниваем язык браузера с имеющимися, если нет совпадения, по умолчанию английский язык(можете поменять).

$lang === 'en' ? '' : (in_array($lang, $acceptLang) ? header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]) : '');//Редирект на другие языки, если их нет, пользователь остается на английском.
```

А в целом, вы уверены, что стоит для каждого языка отдельную страницу создавать? Что если у вас будет 100 страниц с разными языками и нужно будет для каждого что то добавить?

Так же php является шаблонизатором и позволяет упрощать некоторые вещи (почитайте об этом). Например header и footer можно не вставлять в каждую страницу сайте, а создать в отдельном файле и где нужно через include подключать. И так же другие повторяющиеся элементы. И получится, если вам нужно будет что то там отредактировать, то достаточно в одном файле сделать изменения, как они сработают на всех страницах.

А многоязычность на сайте я бы советовал делать через конфиги с переводами.Если интересно, вкратце опишу:

Создаете файл config.php. Я его поместил в папку configs\config.php.

Пишем логику:

```
<?php

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);//Берем первые буквы языка браузера пользователя.

$acceptLang = ['ru', 'de', 'en'];//Ваши языки.
$lang = in_array($lang, $acceptLang) ? $lang : 'en';//Сравниваем язык браузера с имеющимися, если нет совпадения, по умолчанию английский язык(можете поменять).

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;// Если сессия пустая, то ставим, то что пришло из проверки выше.
  else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
  if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
  else if ($_GET['lang'] == "de")
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "de";
  else if ($_GET['lang'] == "ru")
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "ru";
}
require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php"; //Запрашиваем конфиг с переводами
?>
```

Такой конфиг у меня лежит в папке languages и внутри файлы : ru.php, en.php и т. д.
Пример таких конфигов, en.php:

```
<?php
$langarr = array(
"tittleext" => "Exterier",
"tittleint" => "Interior",
"tittlecont" => "Contacts",
"tittleab" => "About Us",
"tittleequa" => "Quality",
"tittleoprj" => "Our projects",
"our_proj" => "Our projects",
"1bl" => "First block",
"2bl" => "Second block",
"3bl" => "Third block"
);
?>
```

ru.php

```
<?php
$langarr = array(
"tittleext" => "Экстерьер",
"tittleint" => "Интерьер",
"tittlecont" => "Контакты",
"tittleab" => "О нас",
"tittleequa" => "Качество",
"tittleoprj" => "Наши проекты",
"our_proj" => "Наши проекты",
"1bl" => "Первый блок",
"2bl" => "Второй блок",
"3bl" => "Третий блок"
);
?>
```

И по ключевому слову вставляем куда нам нужно (не забываем только подключить наш конфиг в наши шаблоны).
В самом вверху подключаем:

```
<?php
    include "configs/configlang.php";
 ?>
```

```
А сами переводы вставляем так:
<?php echo $langarr['tittleint'] ?>
```

Если вы хотите сделать переключалку языка:

```
<a href="?lang=de"><img class="lang" src="images/langde.png"></a>
<a href="?lang=en"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a>
<a href="?lang=ru"><img class="lang" src="images/langrus.png"></a>
```

Надеюсь помог.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогли. Перенаправление так и не заработало. А вариант через cofig не подойдет.

Comment: Я скачал ваш проект, у вас все страницы одинаковые. Какие изменения вы хотите увидеть? Просто, чтобы подгружался нужный файл?

Comment: Title разные. Но я уже нашла проблему. Код надо было вставить в самый верх до <!DOCTYPE HTML>. Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Не работали перенаправления, потому что весь код был не в самом верху страницы. Я подняла код выше:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
```

и сразу заработало.

Comment: А переадресацию вы правильно написали, хотите сказать? При наличие данного массива 
`header('Location: /index-'.$sites[$lang].'.php');` явно работать не будет.
Вот, что в данном случае получается `http://test.com/index-/index-ru.php.php`

Comment: Нет, пытаюсь вставить ваши примеры перенаправления и все работет, но когда получает язык, которого нет и подкидывает EN), то редиректит с ошибкой

Comment: @Hi_TecH А как быть с файлом index.php в корне? Он ведь должен быть. Или просто оставить в нем наш php код и этого будет достаточно?

Comment: Для тех, кто будет читать позже. Если язык отсутствует в списке то редирект идет на файл где наш код и находится. Получается у нас бесконечный редирект, отсюда и ошибка. Исправить ошибку можно так: замените функцию перенаправления на эту : `$lang === 'en' ? '' : (in_array($lang, $acceptLang) ? header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]) : '');`.Кстати, весь код должен быть в основном шаблоне, куда пользователь будет сразу попадать при переходе по ссылке на сайт, в этом же шаблоне будет англ язык (ваш случай index.php). В основном ответе я тоже обновил код, можете оттуда скопировать, там удобнее.